# Thumbnail for video in UNNotificationAttachment is all gray

Tags: ios, cocoa, cocoa-touch, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

This has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60812895/ios-rich-notifications-sending-mp4-files-result-in-transparent-thumbnails) 2 years ago. I am having the same problem and I cannot figure out if this is purely iOS bug or does my code contribute to the resulting grayscale image? My payload contains a download url to a mp4 file, I download this file using urlSession and store the file in the file system. The video plays fine in expanded mode of notification, but for some reason the thumbnail only has gray colors. App like `Nest` seem to have the same problem.

```
        NSData* data = //the data returned from urlSessionDownloadTask            
        NSString *key = [url lastPathComponent];
        NSURL *tempDirectory = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:NSTemporaryDirectory() isDirectory:YES];
        NSURL *fileURL = [tempDirectory URLByAppendingPathComponent:key];

        NSError *diskWriteError;
        const BOOL writeToDiskSucceeded = [data writeToURL:fileURL options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&diskWriteError];
        if (!writeToDiskSucceeded) {
            completion(nil, @"writing error");
        } else {
            NSError *attachmentError;
            UNNotificationAttachment *attachment = [UNNotificationAttachment attachmentWithIdentifier:@"media-id"
                                                                                                        URL:fileURL
                                                                                                    options:
                                                          @{ UNNotificationAttachmentOptionsThumbnailTimeKey : @(1) }
                                                                                                      error:&attachmentError];
    .
    .
    ///  modify mutable content here to add attachment
```

[image]

Comment: Sounds like an iOS bug to me.. Have you played around with different media formats, different `UNNotificationAttachmentOptionsThumbnailTimeKey`'s  and/or different `UNNotificationAttachmentOptionsTypeHintKey`'s?

The 2y old answer suggests separate thumbnail/video downloads and using a content extension. Or using gifs in the first place..

Comment: Those are the first things I’ve tried. Neither helped. It’s clearly an ios bug and I’m looking for an explanation of what could be happening behind the scene. Unfortunately the linked post is the only report I’ve found prior to my posting.

Comment: My working solution right now is separating the thumbnail from the actual video like the answer in the linked post